# Combine selected columns of multiple rows into one string

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, string-aggregation

Say I have the following table:

```
table xyz

+------+--------+--------+
| id   | field1 | field2 |
+------+--------+--------+
|    3 | ABC    | 123    |
|    4 | GHI    | 432    |
|    5 | NULL   | 444    |
+------+--------+--------+
```

To concatenate selected columns (field1 and field2) I can use the following query:

```
select coalesce(field1, '') || ' ' || coalesce(field2::text, '') from xyz;
```

This gives the following result:

```
ABC 123
GHI 432
222
```

How do I merge all the result rows to one row? I'd like to achieve the following

```
ABC 123, GHI 432, 444
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/535f6/1/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  array_agg

```
SELECT array_agg(coalesce(field1, '') || ' ' || coalesce(field2::text, '') )
FROM xyz
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/535f6/7

Comment: `string_agg()` would be more approriate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  using string_agg is sqlfiddle don't work ..

Comment: Of course it does: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c7d42/1

Comment: I see  nothings in sqlfiddle

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/535f6/11

Comment: same  .. as the above

Comment: sqlfiddle is extremely unreliable anyway. Use [this](https://rextester.com/OPEGX77601) or [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9cb6c444407966a30d82c42f7f5174e4)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  tanks for useful  .. links

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your solution!